# How to stream to a wowza media server?

Tags: java, video, streaming, video-streaming, wowza

I want to be able to send video stream from my application to a wowza media server.
Is it possible and what protocols do I need to support(I am working on a J2ME based platform)? Any links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes, it is possible.   Do so with [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol).

Two example applications that can do this include [Flash Media Live Encoder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/flashmediaencoder/) and [Wirecast](http://www.telestream.net/wire-cast/wirecast.htm).  Good luck, it's a non-trivial exercise to do so from scratch.

Comment: Doesn't he need to code anything? I am on the same subject with ASP.NET and C#.I used wirecast for an example but aren't we supposed to write our own code that takes video from a camera and encode/decode it and send to Wowza?

Comment: @OkayGuy: Yes, he'll need to code something.  But the range of work will depend a lot on what libraries and platforms and phones he is working with.  There is not enough information to go farther.  Best follow up with your own question(s) with as specific information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Wowza Media Server will support RTMP, RTSP, HTTP, RTP, RTMPE protocols.

From your query I guess you want to stream a live video from remote machine/mobile phone/ other devices. For that you need an encoder. Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder, Wirecast Encoder, FFMEG ( its really a great command line utility tool ), VLC are the encoders for PC/servers. If you are planning to stream live video from mobile phone then you should use mobile based encoders like [spydroid](https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/), Livu.

let me know for more help